# Not able to deploy Spring-based application after migrating from `Mule 3.x` to `Mule 4.x`

Tags: java, mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I have a `Maven` and `Spring`-based application that I am trying to deploy on `Mule 4` but getting following exception.

Do I need to create this file explicitly ?

```
ERROR 2023-03-15 11:14:38,512 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.module.deployment.internal.DefaultArchiveDeployer: Artifact descriptor does not exists: I:\mule4\apps\my-order-service\META-INF\mule-artifact\mule-artifact.json
org.mule.runtime.module.artifact.api.descriptor.ArtifactDescriptorCreateException: Artifact descriptor does not exists: I:\mule4\apps\my-order-service\META-INF\mule-artifact\mule-artifact.json
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't migrate the Mule 3 application to Mule 4. Note that Mule 4 is not compatible with Mule 3 applications. You should read the [documentation and migration guide](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/index-migration) before starting.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to deploy a Maven and Spring-based application on Mule 4, but the required **mule-artifact.json** file is missing.

1. In your Maven and Spring-based application, navigate to the **src/main/resources** directory.
2. Create a new directory structure: **META-INF/mule-artifact**
3. Inside the mule-artifact directory, create a new file named **mule-artifact.json**
4. Add the following content to the **mule-artifact.json** file:

```json
{
  "minMuleVersion": "4.1.0",
  "classLoaderModelLoaderDescriptor": {
    "id": "mule",
    "attributes": {
      "exportedResources": []
    }
  },
  "bundleDescriptorLoader": {
    "id": "mule",
    "attributes": {}
  }
}
```

Make sure to replace the **minMuleVersion** value with the minimum Mule runtime version your application requires.

Comment: Thanks Fadi, after following the steps above, I am getting this error: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid artifact descriptor: "my-order-service". Mandatory field "name" is missing or has an invalid value.`

Comment: Better to start with a minimum mule-artifact.json with only the `minMuleVersion`. The other values can be autogenerated with current versions of the Mule Maven Plugin in most cases.

Comment: I added params  ` "name": "my-order-service"` and  `"requiredProduct": "MULE_EE"` in the file and now a different  error is showing up `Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.javassist:javassist:pom:3.27.0-GA`